# Android - Rotating a Button and stopping it

Tags: android, animation, rotation

I have a button widget that I had a successful rotation animation on but then it just goes back to the original position. How do I get it to stop?

Here is my xml rotate:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<rotate
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:fromDegrees="0"
    android:toDegrees="90"
    android:pivotX="50%"
    android:pivotY="50%"
    android:repeatCount="0"
    android:duration="1200" />
```

and my java:

```
Button tx = (Button)v;
tx.startAnimation(AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(this, R.anim.rotateit));
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `android:fillAfter="true"` and `android:fillEnabled="true"`

Check the Animation xml specifications:
http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/animation/Animation.html

Comment: Thanks that's great, as a noob the documentation completely confuses at times